# how to create this table with HTML or MARKDOWN only?

Tags: html, markdown

I need to create a document with the table below, it can be either in HTML or in MARKDOWN, but I simply cannot do it. The difficult is in splitting the *LATAM* and *ITPT* into multiple rows. Can someone help please?

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this using `colspan` and `rowspan` on html based on table.

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">HCM</td>
    <td>C88</td>
    <td>C7Z</td>
    <td>C6Z</td>
    <td>CHR</td>
    <td>CHR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5" style="writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-orientation: upright;">LATAM</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using colspan and rowspan you can manipulate how each td is displayed, for example to output the structure you have shown in your design containing `LATAM`, you are required to use `rowspan=5`. This will indicate that the said td element will 'stretch', for want of a better word, over 5 rows.

**Note** I understand you have asked for this to be done in HTML only, the height and border are for better visualization.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      HCM
    </td>
    <td>
      C88
    </td>
    <td>
      C7Z
    </td>
    <td>
      C7H
    </td>
    <td>
      C6Z
    </td>
    <td>
      CHR
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      BR
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan=5 style=>
      L<br>A<br>T<br>A<br>M
    </td>
    <td>
      AR
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      CL
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      CO
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      MX
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      VE
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      ES
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      NA
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan=5 style=>
      I<br>T<br>P<br>T
    </td>
    <td>
      IT
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      PT
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.break {
word-break: break-all;
width: 1em;
letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>HCM</td>
    <td>C88</td>
    <td>C7Z</td>
    <td>C7H</td>
    <td>C6Z</td>
    <td>CHR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>BR</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=5 class="break">LATAM</td>
    <td>AR</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CL</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CO</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MX</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VE</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ES</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NA</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 class="break">ITPT</td>
    <td>IT</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PT</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Relatively painstaking, but it works